# How to decode multiple column into string type? (back to original type)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, encode, forecasting

I have a data like this:
[image]

I want to predict the count column based on that data.
But firstly, I have already encoded it using LabelEncoder.

The code that I'm using to encode this data is:

```
def dummyEncode(df)
Hasil = []
columnsToEncode = list(Hasilatribut)
le = LabelEncoder()
for feature in columnsToEncode:
    try:
        df[feature] : le.fit_transform(df[feature]).astype(float)
    except:
            print('Error encoding '+feature)
return df
```

And the result of my encoding is:[image]

At the last step of my forecasting, I want to transform the 'date', 'tablename', and 'attributename' to the original type.
I've already use inverse_transform, but I still get error.

I also try this:
[image]

The result is still like the 'hasil' output.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What error do you get with the inverse_transform?

Comment: Do you store the `LabelEncoder` trained instance for each column?

Comment: I write le.inverse_transform(hasil), and the error said le is not defined

Comment: You need to store each `LabelEncoder` in a dictionary (for instance) and return it with the dataframe (`df`).

Comment: I have store LabeleEncoder for column date, tablename, attributename. But the result is still in float.

Comment: i've add my code in LabelEncoder